# Adding custom directive to a slot in vuejs render function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to create a renderless component which adds custom directive to it's root slot, and also encapsulates some behavior related to that directive.

I know I can use the `createElement()`, define `directives` as a part of its options, and get a `VNode` back. I also know that I have access to the slot in the render function via `this.$slots.default[0]`. This already holds a `VNode` in it, so I cannot pass it to the `createElement()` to add a directive. Next thing I know is that I can access the existing directives of a `VNode` through its properties (`VNode.data.directives...`).

Can I somehow combine all this to take a root slot, and add a directive to  it without creating wrapper element? Any help / explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Is there some sort of toy example you could give for what you want? I am not sure I understand what this complex design would allow you to do that you can't do with basic components and directives.

Comment: I'll try that here in the comment first, maybe it helps: I have an external library which provides a directive I can place on some of my components. For each of these components I need also a special behavior in mounted hook to correct for one specific issue caused by a combination of already mention library with another library. I would like to create a renderless component which would encapsulate adding this mounted hook + directive to its slot so I could use it around my components.

Comment: I would try: 1. mixin and intercept created/beforeCreate, 2. wrapper directive, 3. additional directive  to manipulate element, 4. functional 'proxy' component

Comment: So seems like what I invisioned is not exactly technically possible right ? adding directive to a slot from a render function I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```js
export default {
    functional: true,
    render(h, ctx) {
        const slots = ctx.slots();
        const slot = slots.default[0];
        slot.data.directives = slot.data.directives || [];
        slot.data.directives.push({
            name: 'custom-directive',
        });
        return slot;
    },
};
```